# jsf fill form fields when field onblur

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, ajax4jsf

I'm new in jsf, and can't find how to do the next thing:
I'm trying to create a form with 8 fields (inputs). after the user enters data into the first input, when he onblur's that input I want to make a select query and get all other fields values and then fill the inputs with those values.

I think it's can be done using ajax? I can't find any example that does this.

Any help will be appriciated,

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Ajax can be used for this. You just attach a `<f:ajax>` to the first input which hooks on the `blur` event and has a listener which prepares the desired data and finally re-renders the other inputs.

E.g.

```
<h:inputText id="input1" value="#{bean.input1}">
    <f:ajax event="blur" listener="#{bean.input1Listener}" render="input2 input3 input4" />
</h:inputText>
<h:inputText id="input2" value="#{bean.input2}" />
<h:inputText id="input3" value="#{bean.input3}" />
<h:inputText id="input4" value="#{bean.input4}" />
```

with

```
public void input1Listener() {
    input2 = "new input2 value";
    input3 = "new input2 value";
    input4 = "new input4 value";
}
```

Comment: thank's!! after the form is re-render, the focus goes to the first input.. how can I set the focus on another input? is there an event for after re-render, or somthing like that? thank's again.